# CloudFormation Cross-Region Reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

When you are running multiple CloudFormation stacks within the same region, you are able to share references across stacks using [CloudFormation Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

However, outputs cannot be used for cross region references as that documentation highlights.

> You can't create cross-stack references across regions. You can use the intrinsic function Fn::ImportValue to import only values that have been exported within the same region.

How do you reference values across regions in CloudFormation?

For an example to follow, I have a [Route 53 hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html) deployed in `us-east-1`. However, I have a backend in `us-west-2` that I want to create a [DNS-validated ACM certificate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-certificate-validation-using-dns-with-aws-certificate-manager/) which requires a reference to the hosted zone in order to be able to create the appropriate CNAME for prove ownership.

How would I go about referencing that hosted zone id created in `us-east-1` from within `us-west-2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### CDK 2.x

There is a new Stack property called `crossRegionReferences` which you can enable to add cross region references. It's as simple as this:

```js
const stack = new Stack(app, 'Stack', {
  crossRegionReferences: true,
});
```

Under the hood, this does something similar to the above answers by using custom resources and Systems Manager. From the [CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#crossregionreferences):

> **crossRegionReferences?**
> Enable this flag to allow native cross region stack references.
>
> Enabling this will create a CloudFormation custom resource in both the producing stack and consuming stack in order to perform the export/import
>
> This feature is currently experimental

More details from the [CDK core package README](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/main/packages/@aws-cdk/core#accessing-resources-in-a-different-stack-and-region):

> You can enable the Stack property `crossRegionReferences`
> in order to access resources in a different stack *and* region. With this feature flag
> enabled it is possible to do something like creating a CloudFront distribution in `us-east-2` and
> an ACM certificate in `us-east-1`.
>
> When the AWS CDK determines that the resource is in a different stack *and* is in a different
> region, it will "export" the value by creating a custom resource in the producing stack which
> creates SSM Parameters in the consuming region for each exported value. The parameters will be
> created with the name '/cdk/exports/${consumingStackName}/${export-name}'.
> In order to "import" the exports into the consuming stack a [SSM Dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm)
> is used to reference the SSM parameter which was created.
>
> In order to mimic strong references, a Custom Resource is also created in the consuming
> stack which marks the SSM parameters as being "imported". When a parameter has been successfully
> imported, the producing stack cannot update the value.

#### CDK 1.x

If you are on CDK 1.x, continue using the workaround that others have shared.

Answer (score 37):

The easiest way I have found of doing this is writing the reference you want to share (i.e. your hosted zone id in this case) to the [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) and then referencing that value in your "child" stack in the separate region using a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Fortunately, this is incredibly easy if your templates are created using [Cloud Development Kit (CDK)](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk).

For the custom resource to read from SSM, you can use something like this:

```js
// ssm-parameter-reader.ts

import { Construct } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { AwsCustomResource, AwsSdkCall } from '@aws-cdk/custom-resources';

interface SSMParameterReaderProps {
  parameterName: string;
  region: string;
}

export class SSMParameterReader extends AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
    const { parameterName, region } = props;

    const ssmAwsSdkCall: AwsSdkCall = {
      service: 'SSM',
      action: 'getParameter',
      parameters: {
        Name: parameterName
      },
      region,
      physicalResourceId: Date.now().toString() // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
    };

    super(scope, name, { onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall });
  }

  public getParameterValue(): string {
    return this.getData('Parameter.Value').toString();
  }
}
```

To write the hosted zone id to parameter store, you can simply do this:

```js
// route53.ts (deployed in us-east-1)

import { PublicHostedZone } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53';
import { StringParameter } from '@aws-cdk/aws-ssm';

export const ROUTE_53_HOSTED_ZONE_ID_SSM_PARAM = 'ROUTE_53_HOSTED_ZONE_ID_SSM_PARAM';

/**
 * Other Logic
 */

const hostedZone = new PublicHostedZone(this, 'WebsiteHostedZone', { zoneName: 'example.com' });

new StringParameter(this, 'Route53HostedZoneIdSSMParam', {
  parameterName: ROUTE_53_HOSTED_ZONE_ID_SSM_PARAM,
  description: 'The Route 53 hosted zone id for this account',
  stringValue: hostedZone.hostedZoneId
});
```

Lastly, you can read that value from the parameter store in that region using the custom resource we just created and use that to create a certificate in `us-west-2`.

```js
// acm.ts (deployed in us-west-2)

import { DnsValidatedCertificate } from '@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager';
import { PublicHostedZone } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53';

import { ROUTE_53_HOSTED_ZONE_ID_SSM_PARAM } from './route53';
import { SSMParameterReader } from './ssm-parameter-reader';

/**
 * Other Logic
 */

const hostedZoneIdReader = new SSMParameterReader(this, 'Route53HostedZoneIdReader', {
  parameterName: ROUTE_53_HOSTED_ZONE_ID_SSM_PARAM,
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
const hostedZoneId: string = hostedZoneIdReader.getParameterValue();
const hostedZone = PublicHostedZone.fromPublicHostedZoneId(this, 'Route53HostedZone', hostedZoneId);

const certificate = new DnsValidatedCertificate(this, 'ApiGatewayCertificate', { 'pdx.example.com', hostedZone });
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I used this for global accelerator as that needed arns from across regions

Comment: How to do a similar thing with something like serverless framework??

Comment: @Marzouk Yup. Serverless framework provides the free dashboard which has a feature called outputs that lets you export values at deployment time like CloudFormation ARN's, etc and then import them using the ${outputs} syntax. More details: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/dashboard/output-variables/

Comment: Unfortunately if the parameter in the store changes, I don't believe cloudformation will detect this and redeploy with the updated value.

Answer (score 17):

The cdk library has been updated, the code avove needs to be changed to the following:

```js
import { Construct } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { AwsCustomResource, AwsSdkCall } from '@aws-cdk/custom-resources';
import iam = require("@aws-cdk/aws-iam");

interface SSMParameterReaderProps {
  parameterName: string;
  region: string;
}

export class SSMParameterReader extends AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
    const { parameterName, region } = props;

    const ssmAwsSdkCall: AwsSdkCall = {
      service: 'SSM',
      action: 'getParameter',
      parameters: {
        Name: parameterName
      },
      region,
      physicalResourceId: {id:Date.now().toString()} // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
    };

    super(scope, name, { onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall,policy:{
        statements:[new iam.PolicyStatement({
        resources : ['*'],
        actions   : ['ssm:GetParameter'],
        effect:iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      }
      )]
    }});
  }

  public getParameterValue(): string {
    return this.getResponseField('Parameter.Value').toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023-01-16** with `cdkv2` version `2.56.0` in a `projen` generated projects (hence respecting eslint rules and best practices for formatting etc.) :

```js
import {
  aws_iam as iam,
  custom_resources as cr,
} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

interface SSMParameterReaderProps {
  parameterName: string;
  region: string;
}

export class SSMParameterReader extends cr.AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
    const { parameterName, region } = props;

    const ssmAwsSdkCall: cr.AwsSdkCall = {
      service: 'SSM',
      action: 'getParameter',
      parameters: {
        Name: parameterName,
      },
      region,
      physicalResourceId: { id: Date.now().toString() }, // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
    };

    super(scope, name, {
      onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall,
      policy: {
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            resources: ['*'],
            actions: ['ssm:GetParameter'],
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
          }),
        ],
      },
    });
  }

  public getParameterValue(): string {
    return this.getResponseField('Parameter.Value').toString();
  }
};
```

Could not edit the post above ...