# How to reference JSON values from a parameter store using a AwsCustomResource in AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-parameter-store

I have been using the solution proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774628/91403) in order to access configurations stored in an AWS parameter.

```js
export class SSMParameterReader extends AwsCustomResource {
  constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: SSMParameterReaderProps) {
    const { parameterName, region } = props;

    const ssmAwsSdkCall: AwsSdkCall = {
      service: 'SSM',
      action: 'getParameter',
      parameters: {
        Name: parameterName
      },
      region,
      physicalResourceId: {id:Date.now().toString()}
    };

    super(scope, name, { onUpdate: ssmAwsSdkCall,policy:{
        statements:[new iam.PolicyStatement({
        resources : ['*'],
        actions   : ['ssm:GetParameter'],
        effect:iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      }
      )]
   }});
  }

  public getParameterValue(): string {
    return this.getResponseField('Parameter.Value').toString();
  }
}
```

Now I came across a parameter in the JSON format and have found no way to access its value. I can't seem to be able to parse it. Here is one example: `{ "subnetId": "subnet-xxxxxx" }`.

I have tried modifying the code in several ways but mainly in the likes of:

```js
  ...

  public getParameterValue(path: string): string {
    return this.getResponseField(`Parameter.Value.${path}`).toString();
  }
```

How can I extract the `subnetId` value?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, as SSM Parameters are simple strings. Consider creating separate parameters for each key, and placing them in a hierarchy.

Comment: That would be amazing, except that I don't control the parameters :(

Comment: Cant you load the string into a CR convert the str to json and return the value, and when reference the CR value? Have done similar things with Cloudformation, but not with CDK.

Comment: Any kind of `JSON.parse` doesn't seem to work since at the synth time there is only a `[Symbol()]` available and that JSON.parse belongs to JS world and not a CloudFormation template thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lambda-backed custom resource (CR), you can fetch the parameter and parse the JSON string within the custom resource handler itself.  The solution below supports (1) optional cross-region parameters and (2) an arbitrary number of keys in the stringified parameter.

#### Step 1: Define a custom resource

For convenience, I encapsulate the [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CustomResource.html), the [provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.Provider.html), and the lambda handler in a construct wrapper. Pass the SSM parameter name and optionally a region as props. The default region is the stack's region.

```js
// GetJsonParamCR.ts

export interface GetJsonParamCRProps {
  parameterName: string;
  region?: string;
}

export class GetJsonParamCR extends Construct {
  readonly customResource: CustomResource;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: GetJsonParamCRProps) {
    super(scope, id);

    const func = new nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, "GetJsonParamLambda", {
      entry: path.join(__dirname, "index.ts"),
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      bundling: { externalModules: ["@aws-sdk/client-ssm"] },
    });

    const paramArn = Stack.of(this).formatArn({
      region: props.region,
      service: "ssm",
      resource: "parameter",
      resourceName: props.parameterName,
      arnFormat: ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME,
    });

    func.addToRolePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["ssm:GetParameter"],
        resources: [paramArn],
      })
    );

    const provider = new cr.Provider(this, "ProviderCR", {
      onEventHandler: func,
    });

    this.customResource = new CustomResource(this, "Resource", {
      resourceType: "Custom::GetJsonParam",
      serviceToken: provider.serviceToken,
      properties: props,
    });
  }
}
```

#### Step 2: Define the CR lambda hander

The Lambda code first gets the parameter with the JS SDK v3 (preloaded with 18.x Lambdas). Then it parses the parameter string and returns the key-value pairs.  I am omitting error handling for simplicity.

```js
// index.ts

export const handler = async (
  event: Omit<lambda.CdkCustomResourceEvent, "ResourceProperties"> & {
    ResourceProperties: GetJsonParamCRProps & { ServiceToken: string };
  }
): Promise<lambda.CdkCustomResourceResponse> => {
  if (event.RequestType === "Delete") return {};

  const { parameterName, region } = event.ResourceProperties;

  const client = new SSMClient({ region: region ?? process.env.AWS_REGION });

  const cmd = new GetParameterCommand({ Name: parameterName });

  const res = await client.send(cmd);
  const parsed = JSON.parse(res.Parameter?.Value ?? "{}");

  return { Data: parsed };
};
```

#### Step 3: Add the CR to a stack

Instantiate the CR in a stack. The `CfnOutput` is added to illustate how to consume the value. Upon deployment, the output value will print to the console: `MyStackDD013518.SubnetId = subnet-xxxxxx`.

Note that this solution supports a JSON parameter with multiple keys (e.g. `r.customResource.getAttString("anotherKey")`).

```js
// MyStack.ts

export class GetJsonParamStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const r = new GetJsonParamCR(this, "GetJsonParamCR", {
      parameterName: "myJsonParam",
      region: "eu-central-1",
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "SubnetId", {
      value: r.customResource.getAttString("subnetId"),
    });
  }
}
```

---

### Alternative solution: no Custom Resource, no cross-region support

OP explicitly requires use of a custom resource and implicitly needs to support cross-region parameters.  If these two requirements are relaxed, the solution is much simpler. Use the [StringParameter.valueFromLookup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#static-valuewbrfromwbrlookupscope-parametername) static method.  `valueFromLookup` is a so-called [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html), which makes the `GetParameter` SDK call at synth-time (on the first run), and caches the result.  Because the resolved parameter value is available at synth-time, you can parse it directly within your CDK code.

As above, a `CfnOutput` value is added for illustration.  It returns `subnet-xxxxxx`.

```js
export class NoCustomResourceStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const param = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, "myJsonParam");
    // this ternary check handles the dummy context value the CDK sets internally on first run
    const subnetId = param.startsWith("dummy-value") ? "dummy" : JSON.parse(param)?.subnetId;

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "SubnetId", {
      value: subnetId,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Will test it today but it totally looks like it will solve the problem